# oracle12c,sql,group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, oracle12c

the original sql is:

```
select c.col1,a.col2,count(1) from table_1 a,table_2 b.table_3 c where a.key =b.key and b.no = c.no group by c.col1,a.col2 having count(a.col2) >1;
```

the output:

```
c.col1  a.col2 count(1)
aa1     bb1    2
aa1     bb2    3
aa1     bb3    5
aa2     bb8    1
aa2     bb1    4
```

i try to get the output set which is like

```
c.col1   count(1)
aa1        10
aa2        5
```

how to write the sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "simple" option is to use your current query (rewritten to use `JOIN`s, which is nowadays preferred way of *joining* tables) as an inline view:

```
  SELECT col1, SUM (cnt)
    FROM (  SELECT c.col1, a.col2, COUNT (*) cnt     --> your current query begins here
              FROM table_1 a
                   JOIN table_2 b ON a.key = b.key
                   JOIN table_3 c ON c.no = b.no
          GROUP BY c.col1, a.col2
            HAVING COUNT (a.col2) > 1)               --> and ends here
GROUP BY col1;
```

---

Or, remove `a.col2` from `select`:

```
  SELECT c.col1, COUNT (*) cnt
    FROM table_1 a
         JOIN table_2 b ON a.key = b.key
         JOIN table_3 c ON c.no = b.no
GROUP BY c.col1, a.col2
  HAVING COUNT (a.col2) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do that if you simply remove `col2` from your select and group by. Because `col2` will no longer be returned, you should also remove the having statement. I think it should look something like this:

```sql
select
    c.col1,
    count(1)
from
    table_1 a,
    table_2 b,
    table_3 c
where
    a.key = b.key
    and b.no = c.no
group by
    c.col1;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: In which case, you could add this:
having count(1)>1

Answer (score 0):

use sum() and only group by for the col1

```
select c.col1, sum(a.col2) as total
    from table_1 a,table_2 b.table_3 c 
    where a.key =b.key and b.no = c.no 
    group by c.col1;
```

**Output---**

```
c.col1   total
aa1        10
aa2        5
```

Comment: the having statement is the emphasis!~~